# FindFit giving weird values on a logistic equation

Tags: fitting, homework

I was trying to fit a set of data onto a [logistic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html), however it ended up telling me that the initial value when $t=0$ is greater than the maximum limit, thus I am led to believe that it isn't working.

My approach:

Here are the data points  with the top row being day and the second row being height (cm)

$\begin{matrix}7&14&21&28&35&42&49&56&63&70&77&84\\17.93&36.36&67.76&98.1&131&169.5&205.5&228.3&247.1&250.5&253.8&254.5\end{matrix}$

I put them into mathematica by the following:

```
points={{7,17.93},{14,36.36},{21,67.76},{28,98.1},{35,131},{42,169.5},{49,205.5},{56,228.3},{63,247.1},{70,250.5},{77,253.8},{84,254.5}};
```

I need to fit this data into this equation

$\frac{C}{1+\frac{C-N_0}{N_0}e^{-rt}}$, where $C$ is defined as the maximum possible height, $N_0$ is the height when $t=0$, $r$ is some constant, $e$ is Euler's Constant and $t$ is time

Since $C$ and $N$ are already used by mathematica, i used $c$ and $n$

```
FindFit[points,c/(1+((c-n)/n)*E^(-r*t)),{c,n,r},t]
```

The output was:

```
{c->163.363, n->653566, r->236.408}
```

What have I done wrong to get these values? Also I am positive I have the correct equation as this is what the assignment tells us is the equation and all the other questions work. (Although they are a different style and we are given $N_0$ and $C$ in those ones)

My expected output for $C$ and $N_0$ I believe is around

```
{c->256, n->9}
```

However I am unsure about $r$ but believe it to be under $1$ and positive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite common a problem when doing nonlinear fit. As far as I know, the most general and effective solution for it is to give the fitted parameters a good enough start value, which you've already known for your specific problem:

```
exp = c/(1 + ((c - n)/n)*E^(-r*t));
FindFit[points, exp, {{c, 256}, {n, 9}, r}, t]
Show[Plot[exp /. %, {t, 7, 84}], ListPlot@points]
```

> ```
> {c -> 261.04, n -> 12.3092, r -> 0.0877072}
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know you could give the variables a rough starting value.

Answer (score 4):

If "diagnostics" or standard errors are required you can use `NonlinearModelFit` with the starting values:

```
fun = c n/(n + (c - n) Exp[-r t]);
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[points, fun, {{c, 256}, {n, 9}, r}, t]
```

Visualizing fit:

```
Show[ListPlot[points], Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 90}]]
```

[image]

You can get model:

```
nlm//Normal
```

yielding

```
3213.19/(12.3092 + 248.73 E^(-0.0877072 t))
```

You can look at model properties:

```
nlm["Properties"]
```

For example:

```
nlm["AdjustedRSquared"]
```

yields 0.999586.

Or

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]